# Were there more “out-of-universe” or “JKR-made-up” magical creatures in Harry Potter universe?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-creatures

**Were there more “out-of-universe” or “JK Rowling-made-up” magical creature types/species in Harry Potter universe?**

By “out-of-universe”, I mean creatures that exist(ed) in folklore/literature/fiction outside of JK Rowling (JKR) books – such as vampires, mermaids, phoenixes, grindylows or dragons (as opposed to kneazles which JKR invented).

In other words, **did JKR invent more magical creatures than she borrowed wholesale from other works/folklore?**

Clarifications:

- The answer should be based on precise count as opposed to random estimate.

  *Ideally* it should include a full list of creatures counted as either “out-of-universe” or “made up”, or at least a reference to existing breakdown.
- The count needs to include full JKR bestiary – e.g. 7 HP books + supplementals (especially *Fantastic Beasts*)
- No need to list anything but the creature's name (e.g. no need for details, which book it's from etc).
- You can choose to either include or ignore creatures considered mythical/non-existant in-universe, e.g. Nargles; if you include them, it's better if they are tabulated separately.
- If the creature shares a name with a "real world" magical creature but is very different from any established descriptions, it counts towards JKR-inventions (personally, I don't recall any examples of this outside Garden Gnomes).
- Plants are out of scope.
- Real world animals with magical properties (e.g. Nagini as magicked up snake, or the python that Harry spoke to in HP1) are in scope, but obviously count towards "out of universe" column.
- Real world animals that clearly have no magical properties (e.g. random birds, or dogs in privet drive) are OUT of scope.
- Mixes/hybrids can be counted however you want as long as you state what you did, unless there are more of them on the list than the margin of difference. (I doubt that there are enough to affect the summary answer). Hermione's half-Kneazle can be counted as a Kneazle.
- Sentient species (Centaurs/Goblins/Trolls/Giants) are in scope but all of the 4 listed here are clearly not JKR-invented. I don't know if HouseElves as JKR describes them exist in folklore.

Comment: Those edits definitely clarify this question.  I had no idea this was a JKR vs folklore count.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[The Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magical_creatures_in_Harry_Potter) article on the creatures has a list of "beasts" in Harry Potter.

Parsing the list comes up with **51 "borrowed wholesale" creatures** and **43 "JKR creatures".** To be fair however, I am certain that most of the "JKR creatures" would best be described as "borrowed, but not entirely" creatures. I am personally not well enough versed in cryptozoology and mythology to tell where a lot of her creatures come from, *but a lot seem very similar to other well known creatures*, just with different names. From my knowledge however here the list divided into the two subcategories:

The groupings are as follows:

**WARNING: A long list follows, feel free to ignore if you don't care about what groupings I chose**

---

### "Borrowed Wholesale: Total = 51":

**Beings(4):**

1. Goblins
2. Hags
3. Humans
4. Vampires

**Beasts(34):**

1. Basilisk
2. Centaur
3. Chimaera
4. Diricrawl (It's a Dodo bird)
5. Dragon(She creates several "types" but come on, they're all dragons.)
6. Erlking
7. Fairy
8. Ghoul
9. Gnome
10. Griffin
11. Grindylow
12. Hippocampus
13. Hippogriff
14. Imp
15. Kappa
16. Kelpie
17. Leprechaun
18. Manticore
19. Merpeople (Again they list different types, but this is a "borrowed" creature.)
20. Mooncalf
21. Nundu
22. Phoenix
23. Pixie
24. Ramora
25. Red cap
26. Re'em
27. Salamander
28. Sea Serpent
29. Sphinx
30. Troll (Again different types, same "borrowed" idea.)
31. Unicorn
32. Werewolf
33. Winged Horse (Once again, there are different types but they represent the same borrowed idea.)
34. Yeti

**Spirits(2):**

1. Ghosts
2. Poltergeists

**Status unknown(12):**

1. Banshees
2. Bicorns
3. Bugbears
4. Boggarts
5. House-elves
6. Cockatrices
7. Dwarfs
8. Fluffy(Cerberus)
9. Giants
10. Hinkypunks (Will-o'-the-wisp)
11. Mummies
12. Veela (Slavic nymphs)

---

### "Invented Creatures: Total = 43":

**Beings(0):**

**Beasts(42):**

1. Ashwinder
2. Augurey
3. Billywig
4. Blast-Ended Skrewt
5. Bowtruckle
6. Bundimun
7. Chizpurfle
8. Clabbert
9. Crup
10. Demiguise
11. Doxy
12. Dugbog
13. Erumpent
14. Fire Crab
15. Fire Slug
16. Flobberworm
17. Fwooper
18. Glumbumble
19. Graphorn
20. Horklump
21. Jarvey
22. Jobberknoll
23. Knarl
24. Kneazle
25. Lethifold
26. Lobalug
27. Mackled Malaclaw
28. Moke
29. Murtlap
30. Niffler
31. Nogtail
32. Occamy
33. Plimpy
34. Pogrebin
35. Porlock
36. Puffskein
37. Quintaped
38. Runespoor
39. Shrake
40. Snidget
41. Streeler
42. Tebo

**Spirits(0)**

**Status unknown(1):**

1. Dementors

Please let me know if you think I have made an error somewhere and I will <strike>argue my point until you agree with me</strike> endeavor to correct my mistake.

Comment: Some of the status unknown ones: Cockatrices - I am almost certain I've seen them in Squaresoft's Final Fantasy II game. Banshees are definitely borrowed. Dementors are most certainly JKR invention based on their backstory (they are equivalet of depression)

Comment: @DVK the first half are ones that were borrowed, the second are JKR inventions, so those are in the correct places that you indicate. [Cockatrice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockatrice) is certainly a borrowed idea.

Comment: @balancedmama AFAIK A Cockatrice is born from an egg laid by a cockerel, hatched under a toad, vs. the Basilisk being born from the egg of a toad, hatched under a cockerel. They are different creatures, but nearly the same in most accounts. I listed them separately as the Wikipedia article sourced in the answer as a list of Harry Potter creatures also listed them separately. I assumed that Cockatrices must appear in *Magical Beasts* or some other non-septology canon.

Comment: According to my sources the Basilisk is born of an egg laid by a cockerel and hatched by a toad.  Pretty sure that is how "Herpo" made one as described my Magical Beasts and Where to Find them too.  So, now I'm really interested in finding out more.  The two terms are both used in different translations of the same verse in The Bible, plus various other sources had led me to believe them the same.  I have seen them  referred to as different by others, though, but had never found a reason why.  I'll definitely have to look at that one up.  I'm interested in your source for the difference.

Comment: I found this, "Cockatrice became seen as synonymous with basilisk when the basiliscus in Bartholomeus Anglicus' De proprietatibus rerum (ca 1260) was translated by John Trevisa as cockatrice (1397).[4] A basilisk, however, is usually depicted without wings." on Wikipedia, but it is on the same article that describes them as also being mortal enemies as seen by people before the Early Middle Ages.  Both are said to hatch from a cock's or chicken's egg incubated by a toad.  So... Different, but not for the reasons you state.

Comment: The [Basilisk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilisk#Accounts) article under Accounts states that they are born in the manner in which I described them. They certainly have been used interchangeably, but the articles I've read have stated that they are different, and that synonymous use comes from * mis-attribution* rather than actual circumstance. In any case, the only reason I listed both was that in the Wikipedia article they are listed separately.

Comment: What about the whomping willow?  It appears to at least be semi-sentient

Comment: Quite a few in the "Status unknown" list are well known to me from D&D and `nethack` back in the 80s Banshees, Bugbears, Cockatrices,
Dwarfs, Cerberus, Giants, Hinkypunks (Will-o'-the-wisp), Mummies are all referenced there, and then of course some of them are even older (Cerberus, Banshees, etc).  Whether JKR *knew* of them or said "Hrm, need some beasts, wheres that first edition Monster Manual I had laying around..." is a different question...

Comment: House-Elves (status unknown) seem to be loosely connected to the Christmas elves.

Comment: I would probably classify both banshees as dementors as "spirits".

Comment: @ivanivan Very late answer, but “Status unknown” means it’s uncertain whether they should be listed as beings, beasts or spirits, not whether they’re JKR-invented or borrowed.

Comment: The article currently also mentions an acromantula, which is a enormous talking spider — like Shelob.